# Symfony 4 -- Form min max validation

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, assert

How to be sure that min < max before validation

here my entity

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="min", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $min;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="max", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $max;
```

in the form :

```
  ->add('min',               NumberType::class,array('required' => false))
  ->add('max',               NumberType::class,array('required' => false))
```

it's an option and min must be inferior to max before validating the form

How can i verify and send a message to the user to change his form if it's not correct.

Thanks

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: isn't there a simpler solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure callback is complicated. Have you already tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this that I can think of.

1. The Callback-Constraint was already mentioned in the comments.
2. Creating your own custom constraint
3. Using the Expression-constraint

Probably the latter is the easiest one. Basically it looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @Assert\Expression("this.getMin() <= this.getMax()")
 */
private $min;

/**
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 */
private $max;
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html

Creating a custom constraint is even more work than the Callback-constraint, so I won't go into details for that, but you can find a good article in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, there is a better solution for Symfony >3.4.

[GreaterThan](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThan.html), GreaterThanOrEqual, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual validation constraints come with `propertyPath` option which allows to specify object property to compare with.

I am quite surprised that it was not implemented earlier.

```
/**
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(
 *     message="Too high",
 *     propertyPath="maxSubscribers")
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(
 *     message="Too high",
 *     value=100000000)
 */
private $min;

/**
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(
 *     message="Too low",
 *     value=1)
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual(
 *     message="Too high",
 *     value=100000000)
 */
private $max;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `min` and `max` validation in `form` for .ex:

```
->add('ordering', NumberType::class, array(
          'attr' => array('min' => 1, 'max' => 100)
     ))
```

Also in `Entity`:

```
// src/Entity/YourFoo.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class YourFoo
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = 120,
     *      max = 180,
     *      minMessage = "You must be at least {{ limit }}cm tall to enter",
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot be taller than {{ limit }}cm to enter"
     * )
     */
     protected $fooNumber;

     ...............................


}
```

Comment: thats not what OP wants. He want to assert that field `min` <= field `max`

Comment: Why do not use `Lifecycle Callbacks`? @Rufinus